# issues importing excel and other files in SQL Server 2022

Tags: sql-server, excel

i am trying to import an excel file into sql server 2022 and i keep having the same errors, i have tried reinstalling it.[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjqGQ.png)

i have also tried the visual studio and downloading the integration system still with no luck. i also can't seem to be able to install it from the feature selection. [feature selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4vjU.png)

Comment: If you have csv file you can import file with bulk insert command.

Comment: Image is not  available. Please share the information in plain text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OPENROWSET()` as below:

```
SELECT * INTO MyTable
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
                'Excel 12.0;Database=C:\MyExcelFile.xlsx;HDR=YES', 
                'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]');
```

*** You can use the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard, which is a graphical tool that can import data from a variety of sources, including Excel.

Open SQL Server Management Studio and connect to the database you want to import the data into.

1. Open SQL Server Management Studio and connect to the database you want to import the data into.
2. Right-click on the database and select "Tasks" > "Import Data".
3. In the "Choose a Data Source" page of the wizard, select "Microsoft Excel" as the source.
4. Browse to the Excel file and select it.
5. In the "Choose a Destination" page, select "SQL Server Native Client" as the destination and enter the database information.
6. Select the table or create a new table to store the data in.
7. Map the columns from the Excel file to the table columns.
8. Run the import process.